# PHP - failed write

Tags: php, file-io, fwrite

I am stuck and in need of a hand.  Hope someone can help?

Anyone have any idea why I am getting "failed write" in this code?

```
$write_file = "/usr/home/public_html/php/users_v2.sql";
$write_handle = fopen($write_file, "w") || die("Couln't open users_v2!");

if (is_writeable($write_file)) {
    if ($write_handle === FALSE) echo 'Failed handle?!';
    if (fwrite($write_handle, "Hi\n") === FALSE) echo "Failed write!\n";
}

fclose($write_handle);
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not sure, but can you check if the program has necessary permissions to write to the file?

Comment: Yeah, I checked that.  777's across the board.  Its so weird.

Comment: Have you checked your server's error logs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using the OR operator when creating your file handle, you are returning a boolean value depending on the operation. So $write_handle will contain true or false, instead of the file resource. A better way to open a file for writing and test that it was successful would be this:

```
$write_handle = fopen($write_file, 'w');
if ($write_handle === false)
{
    die('Could not open file ' . $write_file);
}
```

Additionally, you could use the [`file_put_contents`](https://www.php.net/file_put_contents)`()` function which handles the fopen(), fwrite() and fclose() for you. I only recommend this if you are executing only one write to the same file, as it will be a lot of overhead, and unless you pass the `FILE_APPEND` flag, it will empty the file for every write.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen it used everywhere but the problem is the || die("Couln't open users_v2!");

First I added:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

to see what php is reporting for errors.

```
$write_handle = fopen($write_file, "w") || die("Couln't open users_v2!");
fclose($write_handle);
```

Returns an invalid stream handle error and file handle of 1. Without it the returned file handle is "Resource id #x".

Changing the line to:

```
$write_handle = fopen($write_file, "w"); // || die("Couln't open users_v2!");
```

and your code works fine. Gonna go post this on php.net now.